# usleep() php5 uses 40% of idle CPU

Tags: php, cpu, sleep, idle-processing

Hi guys I have a weird question,

I have a cli php script runs on Centos 5.x which uses usleep (somtimes 1sec, sometimes 2sec, somtimes 100ms it depends) if there is some wait required, but what I have noticed its that once on usleep() it seems to use about 40% of idle CPU:

```
Cpu(s):  5.3%us, 21.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 57.2%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si, 16.1%st
```

any ideas ?
cheers

Comment: Most of the time is spent in kernel mode, try strace on the process to see what syscalls is it invoking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't happen for me with a very simple testcase. Try the following on your system to see if you still get the excessive CPU time.

Script test.php:

```
<?php
for ($n=0;$n<1000;$n++)
{
  usleep(10);
}
?>
```

Then at the command line run: `time php test.php`

My results are as follows:

```
[ar@arctic ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 5.2 (Final)
[ar@arctic ~]$ time php test.php 

real    0m1.020s
user    0m0.013s
sys     0m0.006s
```

You can see that the user and sys time are very very small in comparison to the real (or elapsed) time. i.e. CPU utilisation was very low.

Comment: here you go my times= real: 0m4.941s, user: 0m0.036s, sys: 0m0.036s. but how this one is realeted to the CPU usage anyway ?

Comment: From your results, I would conclude that `usleep` is not your problem. Can you show us what else is in your code around usleep - I presume you are in some sort of loop.

Answer (score 3):

Under Windows systems, if you do not set the time limit of the execution of your script to 0 (`set_time_limit(0);`), the php executable will eat as much as 50% CPU power when using sleep or usleep functions.